# SSL errors when connecting to University Network

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, ssl

To start, I have no problems at all on my home network or on my phone's mobile hotspot.

Basically when I connect to my school's open wifi network I get SSL errors in all my connected applications (chrome, firefox, dropbox, tresorit). I also seem to have no connectivity. I'm on a brand new laptop running ubuntu 16.04.1.

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and have no idea how to troubleshoot this. I've checked all the normal stuff like proxy/system time and everything looks normal.

I'm kind of thinking it is specific to the school's network and my laptop because everyone else seems to be using the wifi network without problems.

I have Gufw firewall installed, but currently disabled which doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.
EDIT:
Here is info on my wifi adapter, I'm starting to think it has something to do with this specific adapter: Intel 3165NGW

> filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
>   license:        GPL
>   author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation >
>   description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
>   firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
>   srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000930bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000950bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000850bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000910bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000810bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F6sv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F5sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000044bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000004bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00009150bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00009050bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00008150bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00008050bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00009132bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00008132bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00009130bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00008130bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F4sv*sd00009030bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F4sv*sd00008030bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00008110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00008010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd0000D050bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd0000C050bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd0000D010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd0000C110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd0000C010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F4sv*sd00001030bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F4sv*sd00000030bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00001150bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000150bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00001050bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000250bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000050bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00001110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00001012bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000012bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd000001F0bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00001132bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000132bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00001130bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000130bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009400bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009000bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd0000520Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005212bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005F10bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005590bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005190bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005090bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005420bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000502Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005020bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009410bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00009310bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009510bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00009200bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00009210bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009112bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000900Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009012bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005202bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005102bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005002bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005200bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000500Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005000bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005400bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005510bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005410bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005412bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005012bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005C10bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005210bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005302bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005310bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005100bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00008110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00008010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003166sv*sd00004210bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003166sv*sd00004310bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004110bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004510bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004410bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003166sv*sd00004212bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004012bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00003165sv*sd00004010bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00001170bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00001070bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008570bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008470bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008272bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008370bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008270bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008062bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008060bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008172bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008170bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008072bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008070bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000370bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000472bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000470bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000272bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000270bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000060bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000172bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000170bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000072bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C420bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C02Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C360bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C370bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C560bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C570bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C462bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C460bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C472bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C470bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C262bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C26Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C260bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C272bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000CC60bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000CC70bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C270bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C760bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C770bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C162bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C062bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C160bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C06Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C060bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C170bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C072bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C070bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004420bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004220bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000402Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004020bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005770bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005170bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005072bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005070bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004360bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004370bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004560bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004570bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Cbc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Ebc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A70bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000486Ebc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004870bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004472bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004470bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004272bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004270bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004162bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004160bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004C70bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004C60bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004170bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004072bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004070bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000462bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000262bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000822bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000422bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000895sv*sd00000222bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000022bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00005260bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004860bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000888sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004822bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004422bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000891sv*sd00004222bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004022bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005027bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005025bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005017bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005015bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005007bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005005bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001027bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001025bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001017bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001015bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001007bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001317bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001327bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005226bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005225bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005221bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005207bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005206bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005205bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005201bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005216bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005215bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005211bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005317bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005315bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005327bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005325bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005307bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005305bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00004820bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C228bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001318bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001328bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001308bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001118bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001128bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001108bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Bsv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001114bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001104bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001004bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001124bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001024bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001314bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001214bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001324bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001224bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
>   alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
>   depends:        cfg80211
>   intree:         Y
>   vermagic:       4.4.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
>   parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
>   parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
>   parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
>   parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
>   parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
>   parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
>   parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
>   parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
>   parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
>   parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
>   parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
>   parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
>   parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
>   parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

Comment: I have had exactly the same problem with my laptop with certain router. Try to connect through other band if this is possible: https://www.google.bg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20wifi%20bands%20ubuntu

Comment: Without specific error messages, we can only guess.  I've given one of the possible causes of the problems below, in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Old answer removed, because I know the core issue now.  The original "guessing" of the issue which was done in the original answer can still be read [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/841387/1).

The issue you are running into is that your network is trying to grab you into a captive portal to "authenticate" on the network.

This means that any web request, when you aren't authenticated on the network, will get you sent to the captive portal.  HSTS protections on the specific sites will result in errors like these, as well as HTTPS errors for "Invalid SSL Certificate Domain" for the HTTPS sites you're requesting.

You will need to go to a *non-HTTPS site* first to get through the captive portal, and then you can browse HTTPS sites without issue, most likely.  You can use any site such as `cnn.com` or something else that doesn't need HTTPS/SSL.  Once you get past the captive portal, you should not see the issue anymore browsing to HTTPS sites.

---

Browser plugins like HTTPS Everywhere can sometimes break this, too, because it tries to remember the certificate that was in use.

Comment: The specific error I'm getting from firefox is: canvas.uw.edu uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: captiveportal.wifi.uw.edu, *.wc.uw.edu Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

Comment: @StormDuck and that's for any site you try and access over HTTPS, correct?

Comment: Yes, every site, but also this includes other applications on my system like dropbox and tresorit applications.

Comment: @StormDuck have you gone through the captive portal first, then tried to use such applications afterwards?  (Web apps won't work if you don't go through the captive portal it's trying to make you auth with first)

Comment: Just resolved it, figured it out. I run https everywhere on my browser so I never made it to the captive portal. As soon as I went to cnn.com with https disabled, everything else started working.